# Polars: execute many operations "over" same grouping

Tags: python, python-polars

Showing a toy example with `K=2` but the question is mostly relevant for high `g` cardinality and `K>>1`:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(
    g=[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    v=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
))

K = 2

df.with_columns((col.v.shift(k+1).over('g').alias(f's{k}') for k in range(K)))
```

```
╭─────┬─────┬──────┬──────╮
│   g ┆   v ┆   s0 ┆   s1 │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆  i64 ┆  i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│   1 ┆   1 ┆ null ┆ null │
│   2 ┆   2 ┆ null ┆ null │
│   1 ┆   3 ┆    1 ┆ null │
│   2 ┆   4 ┆    2 ┆ null │
│   1 ┆   5 ┆    3 ┆    1 │
│   2 ┆   6 ┆    4 ┆    2 │
╰─────┴─────┴──────┴──────╯
```

How can I make sure the grouping by `g` is done only once?

Polars does not seem to optimize for this in the query plan.

I would expect it to run as fast as:

```py
df.group_by('g').agg((col.v.shift(k+1).alias(f's{k}') for k in range(K)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polars caches window expressions. While you may not see this represented in the query plan, the `over` grouping is only done once.

Still, your `over` query will not run as fast as your `group_by` query. This is because `over` has to add the results back into the original data frame.

A fairer comparison would be the query below, which will match the result of the `over` query. As you can see, an additional `join` is required.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "g": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        "v": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    }
)
K = 2

df_shift = (
    df.group_by("g")
    .agg([pl.col("v")] + [pl.col("v").shift(k + 1).alias(f"s{k}") for k in range(K)])
    .explode(["v"] + [f"s{k}" for k in range(K)])
)
result = df.join(df_shift, on=["g", "v"], how="left")
print(result)
```

```
shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ g   ┆ v   ┆ s0   ┆ s1   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 1    ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 3    ┆ 1    │
│ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ 4    ┆ 2    │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
```